# grub can't see linux\no boot menu in Win7

Tags: linux, boot, restart

I have both windows and linux installed.

I created a new partition but got `Grub error:UNKNOWN FILESYSTEM` on restart.  Then I used windows recovery CD and `Bootrec/fixmbr command` to get Grub menu back.

But now I don't see the boot menu.laptop simply boots into windows, also I am unable to boot from any other CD or USB

Comment: Please put your unix/linux related questions in http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall grub on the boot sector. If you use Ubuntu, there is a very easy way to fix it with Ubuntu's live CD using the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool.
I'm not sure if this will work with other Linux distributions but It's worth trying.

If you can't boot from CD or USB you should check your boot priority in the BIOS. Or try to get to boot selection menu (usually by pressing F12) and choose CD\USB over there, anyways, the answer here is in the BIOS and not related to the grub

Comment: changing boot priority is not helping at all,i am able to boot only with windows recovery cd but not with any other cd